# When to use def and val on Gatling scenarios and chains

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I come from a Java background and am taking over a Gatling project where I noticed what seems to me a bit of inconsistency when using what is a val or a def method. The picture below exemplifies that and I was wondering if there's any guidance on what is the best usage for these **within the Gatling context** please.

[image]

These are other examples where I'm not sure what should be used. I'm assuming a Switch makes sense being inside a method but not sure about the others?

```
private def teacherViewResources: ChainBuilder =
    exec(viewResourcesFlow)
      .randomSwitch(
        70.0 -> pause(1,2).exec(teacherLaunchResource),
        10.0 -> pause(1,2).exec(teacherAssignResource),
        20.0 -> pause(1,2).exec(teacherResourcesNext)
      )

  private def teacherLaunchResource: ChainBuilder =
    exec(launchResourcesFlow)

val rootTeacherScenario = scenario("Root Teacher Scenario " + currentScenario.toString)
    .doIfOrElse(currentScenario == PossibleScenarios.BRANCH)(
      feed(userFeederTeacher).during(EXECUTION_TIME_SEC) {
        exec(teacherBranching)
      }

      //For use with atOnceUsers for debugging
      //feed(userFeederTeacher).exec(simulationTeacherBranching)

    )(
      exec {
        session =>
          logger.debug("Invalid teacher scenario chosen")
          session
      }
    )

val loginFlowWithExit = exec(loginFlow).exitHereIfFailed

val teacherBranching = group("teacherBranching") {
    exec(loginFlow)
      .exec(session => sessionSetSessionVariable(session))
      .exec(execFlaggedScenario(teacherDashboard)) // First method to run for a teacher
      .exec(logout())
  }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`val` is evaluated once while `def` is evaluated on every call.
Remember that Gatling DSL components are just builders, not what is executed when your test is running.
Everything that doesn't take a parameter could be a `val`, you just have to make sure you don't end up with using forward references, eg:

broken:

```scala
val foo = exec(???).exec(bar) // here, bar is still null because it's populated later in the code
val bar = exec(???)
```

correct:

```scala
val bar = exec(???)
val foo = exec(???).exec(bar) // fine because bar is already populated
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, thank you for your reply. Sorry, when you say val is evaluated only one what do you mean? And how's that in the context of multiple users coming through a csv file?

Comment: And when you talk about params, does that include the naming for group piece, which would then be turned into a method?

Comment: `val` is what could be seen as a constant or immutable value and, as a function as well. Maybe this post will be helpful for you as well https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book-diffs-val-def-scala-functions/ where there are some semantics `val` vs `def`

Comment: Thanks. I think I am perhaps still failing on seeing what is really immutable inside Gatling. –

Comment: I mean, is a scenario immutable that should be a val? I suppose so.. A chainBuilder, a group, a randomSwitch branch? hmm, I don't know.